# Inequality regarding sum and root

Tags: inequality, summation, roots

I need also your expertise in finding a solution to the following problem:

It is known that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall c \in [1,\infty)$ that $$\sqrt[c]{1} + \sqrt[c]{e^x} \geq \sqrt[c]{1 + e^x} .$$

Let $k \in (0,1)$, Is there an inequality that regards the following problem $$ \sqrt[k]{1} + \sqrt[k]{e^x} \geq \sqrt[k]{1 + e^x},$$ i.e. let $k^\prime \in (1,\infty)$ such that $$ 1 + e^{k^\prime \cdot x} \geq (1 + e^x)^{k^\prime}??$$

I Think that Jensen equality would help but i want to make sure that maybe there is other inequality regarding this manner.

Please advice and and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating with, say, $k'=2$?

Comment: The reverse holds indeed. We have $\sqrt[k] 1 +\sqrt[k]{e^x}\leq\sqrt[k]{1+e^x}$ for $0<k<1$.

Comment: I did evaluate, but i wanted to know whether there is an inequality which i dont know of to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Take $k'=2$, and you get

$$1+e^{2x}\geq 1+e^{2x}+2e^x$$

which is clearly false because $e^x>0$.

So there is no such inequality.

Comment: Why Jensen's inequality can't be used here?

Comment: @user3492773 I don't know about Jensen's inequality sorry...